# selenium can't find CSS selector on Instagram login page

Tags: css, selenium

I'm using selenium + python:

```
notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")
notnow.click()
```

to click the "Not Now" button to turn off Instagram notifications after login through Chromedriver:

[image]

However, I receive the terminal error:

> File "/Applications/Instabot.py", line 23, in  notnow.click()
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

How do I select the turn off browser notifications through "Not Now" @ www.instagram.com after login?

Comment: I changed it to `notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]")` and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.sqdOP  L3NKy')
```